# How do I reference custom EL function in ADF page fragments

Tags: jsf, el, oracle-adf, page-fragments

I would like to create a static (helper) function which will check if a given variable belongs to a set of predefined values. I want to use it as an EL function in order to reference it in a jsff file (via java's EL). The question is: how do I reference the custom function inside the JSFF since it is a page fragment and I cannot access the form templates which the fragment belongs to due to its compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an element from your jsff binded on this function by setting the function's class as the jsff scope in the adfc-config.xml in the "managed-bean" tab and the calling it as follow :

```
<af:outputText
id="pt1"
viewId="#{YOURSCOPE.YOURBEAN.YOURFUNCTION}"
```

You'll get a detailled how to in the documentation here : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/b31974/web_getstarted.htm#ADFFD1746

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. <br/><br/>I followed the approach you suggested me. I tried also to add that statement in the oracle's MDS file (due to customization). It displays me an error message like the following: <br/>`code`Function isInList has an invalid prefix or uses the default namespace which is not defined.  Correct the prefix or in a jsp document, put the function inside a tag that defines the tag library namespace.`code`. <br/><br/>Any ideas?

Comment: At no point should you have to add a statement in the mds. Take the time to follow the getstarted doc provided. Build you java bean, add the function you want to bind, add the bean to the adfc_config.xml as a pageflowscope or build a datacontrol, bind this datacontrol to your jsff